# Working cross-browser with the Speech Synthesis Javascript API in 2020

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, mobile, text-to-speech

It's been around for six years, so I thought I'd give the **Speech Synthesis API** a spin:

- [Speech Synthesis API - CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=speech-synthesis)
- [Speech Synthesis API - W3C](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/)
- [Speech Synthesis API - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis)

Here's my first test:

```js
const vocalWelcome = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Welcome to the Main Men-You. Please select your option.');
vocalWelcome.pitch = 3;
vocalWelcome.rate = 0.95;
window.speechSynthesis.speak(vocalWelcome);
```

I've noticed that despite explicitly setting the `pitch` property to `3`, the voice-pitch is very much higher on **Firefox Mobile 68** and **Chrome Mobile 81** on my Android than it is on **Firefox 75** and **Chrome 81** on my laptop.

Is there anything I can do about this? Do I need to be browser sniffing / device sniffing and then tweaking the `pitch` property accordingly?

Or should I regard this as teething problems because, in 2020, the **Speech Synthesis API** spec is simply not yet ready for production?

Comment: Don't know if you'll have to deal with this, but I had issues with the available voices and default voices chosen for foreign computers.  I used a polyfill, and found the polyfill did not really fix everything.

Comment: Sure. I can see it's not particularly sophisticated - I had to write _"menu"_ as _"men-you"_ above to stop the second syllable from being half-swallowed. But that's fine, becauseI don't want to use it for anything excessively elaborate - I'm simply keen to add a couple of _progressive enhancements_ to my app.

Comment: Speech synthesis is all over the map in support and underlying technologies - most will use whatever the native speech solution is. If you really need a consistent solution consider using [a library](https://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/) or a cloud TTS service.

Comment: @Rounin - Browsers use the underlying speech provider on each platform, with perhaps some sugar on top to determine what they pass. Each OS has it's underlying provider (Windows = SAPI / Media Foundation, iOS/OSX = VoiceOver, Linux = PicoTTS or eSpeak, though that list isn't exhaustive). Also, Google includes its own speech provider, and some browsers use online services in the backend for rendering. You're not guaranteed the same voice unless you use a 3rd party library. Also keep in mind that users' language settings may differ too.

Comment: @Luke - Aha. That's really useful to know. Very helpful. Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: just a fyi, the problem I had wasn't just that the voices were different, but that they just didn't work if I didn't set one explicitly.

Comment: @Luke, if you can post your comments above as an answer, I will accept - thank you, again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speech synthesis is all over the map in support and underlying technologies - most will use whatever the native speech solution is. If you really need a consistent solution consider using a [library](https://www.masswerk.at/mespeak/) or a cloud TTS service (like Polly or Google Wavenet).

Browsers use the underlying speech provider on each platform, with perhaps some sugar on top to determine what they pass. Each OS has it's underlying provider (Windows = SAPI / Media Foundation, iOS/OSX = VoiceOver, Linux = PicoTTS or eSpeak, though that list isn't exhaustive). Also, Google includes its own speech provider, and some browsers use online services in the backend for rendering. You're not guaranteed the same voice unless you use a 3rd party library. Also keep in mind that users' language settings may differ too.